# Create a list with values and key and get the max value

Tags: vba, excel

i have the following dummy data

```
Dim count1 As Integer
Dim count2 As Integer
Dim count3 As Integer
Dim count4 As Integer
Dim count5 As Integer

count1 = 0
count2 = 3
count3 = 2
count4 = 0
count5 = 1
```

Using the following code I add the values to a dictionary

```
 Dim key As Variant
 Dim dic As Object
 Set dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

   dic.Add "Category 1", count1
   dic.Add "Category 2", count2
   dic.Add "Category 3", count3
   dic.Add "Category 4", count4
   dic.Add "Category 5", count5
```

What I would like to do now however is get the Category that belongs to the highest count (in this example
category 2). Any thoughts on how I can extract this value?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) .In short, you'll need to show your code attempts to solve this and where it's not working to get the most help on this site. If you also post a screenshot of a sample of your sheet, that would help us help you more as well.

Comment: @Moosli, ok will keep that in mind. Update my question

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the key first, then the item.

See sample code (note that I use early binding for dictionaries, it makes life so much easier):

```
Sub DictionaryKeyTest()
    Dim d As Scripting.Dictionary
    Set d = New Dictionary
    d.Add 2, "notHighest"
    d.Add 3, "alsoNotHighest"
    d.Add 10, "Highest!"
    d.Add 4, "alsoAlsoNotHighest"

    Debug.Print d(Application.Max(d.Keys))
End Sub
```

If you run this code, the Immediate Window will read:

> Highest!

If you need to run this the other way around, say if several Categories can have the same count value (or some other scenario where the Category *has* to be the key), there's no way to do what you want without looping through all the values to find the largest one. For example:

```
Sub DictionaryHighestItemCounter()
    Dim d As Scripting.Dictionary
    Set d = New Dictionary
    d.Add "notHighest", 2
    d.Add "alsoNotHighest", 2
    d.Add "Highest!", 10
    d.Add "alsoAlsoNotHighest", 4

    Dim highestVal As Long, s As String
    For Each i In d.Keys
        If d(i) > highestVal Then
            highestVal = d(i)
            s = i
        End If
    Next i

    Debug.Print s
End Sub
```

This code will also print

> Highest!

Answer (score 0):

you could use arrays:

```
Option Explicit

Sub GetCategory()    
    Dim catsArray As Variant, valsArray As Variant

    catsArray = Array("Category 1", "Category 2", "Category 3", "Category 4", "Category 5")
    valsArray = Array(0, 3, 2, 0, 1)

    MsgBox "The winner is: " & catsArray(WorksheetFunction.Match(WorksheetFunction.Max(valsArray), valsArray, 0) - 1)
End Sub
```

that would work should you necessarily use variable for values as well:

```
Option Explicit

Sub GetCategory2()
    Dim catsArray As Variant, valsArray As Variant
    Dim count1 As Integer: count1 = 0
    Dim count2 As Integer: count2 = 3
    Dim count3 As Integer: count3 = 2
    Dim count4 As Integer: count4 = 0
    Dim count5 As Integer: count5 = 1

    catsArray = Array("Category 1", "Category 2", "Category 3", "Category 4", "Category 5")
    valsArray = Array(count1, count2, count3, count4, count5)

    MsgBox "The winner is: " & catsArray(WorksheetFunction.Match(WorksheetFunction.Max(valsArray), valsArray, 0) - 1)
End Sub
```